# Messaging architecture for a data processing pipeline

Tags: java, architecture, streaming, pipeline

I have

- an input stream of JSON data (*in*),
- Java processes that modify the JSON data (*A, B, C, ...*),
- an output stream of JSON data (*out*).

They can be wired up point-to-point using JMS queues and arranged as follows:

```
in -> A -> B -> C -> out
```

However, I find the messaging architecture very brittle. If I want to add, remove, or rearrange components, I would have to stop the pipeline, modify configuration to rewire them as needed, then restart the pipeline. This is obviously very tedious when there are dozens of processes involved.

I would like to implement a data processing pipeline that, without downtime, redeploying components, or modifying configuration, allows me to add and remove components at runtime.

```
in -> A -> B -> C -> out
in -> A -> C -> out             // B stopped
in -> D -> A -> C -> out        // D started behind A
in -> D -> A -> C -> B -> out   // B started after C
```

Are there any frameworks or technologies that can help me achieve this out of the box? If not how can I architect a solution?

---

SideNote:

I've been playing around with the idea of implementing a single PipelineManager which listens for registrations. Processes, when started, register with the PipelineManager with a some priority. The PipelineManager consumes from data in, dispatches messages in decreasing order of priority in a request response style, then produces to data out. ZeroMQ would be used to wire the components together. I'm not sure how to implement this using ZeroMQ, and unsure whether this architecture is the right choice to pursue.

Any comments? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

instead of using commands that are directed at specific recipients you'd have more flexibility if you move to a publish-subscribe model where you publish topics where other services interested would go to get data. Most JMS implementations would support that as well as other messaging platforms like Kafka and RabbitMQ